# How to use REST API for mobile App?

Tags: api, rest-api, mobile

I have found on dev docs that REST API is recommended for mobile application.

I have created integration from magento admin panel and tried to access resources with passing access token in header. Getting products and categories list but with limited data only. Also generate guest cart and add product to cart for guest users are working fine. Then I have tried to delete one of product using access token and it got success. It seems security risk if use hard coded access token in app. Also, there is no option for defining resources operations access along with integration in Magento admin panel.

Dev docs provides information about access token authentication for registered customer account only. Is any way for guest user to generate access token dynamically with limited access for read only permission?

I am wondering how to use REST API correctly with mobile app.

Comment: Yes REST API works correctly with Mobile App :) I have created one. In magento web-API when you pass user name and password then it generates token for that specific customer (Which is only valid for 1 hour - configurable from admin)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the details to make the authentication the right way https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html